# Cell Span in JavaFX

Tags: javafx, tableview

Необходимо объединить ячейки(в данном случае несколько колонок в одну строку) в таблице (tableView). Либо сделать что-нибудь, чтобы текст не скрывался из за маленького размера колонки, а просто отображался поверх следующей ячейки, возможно это можно сделать с помощью css, но таких решений я тоже не находил.

Ниже картинка, красным выделен вариант как должно быть.

[image: Красным выделен вариант как должно быть.]

Comment: нашел вот это http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16927356/tableview-cell-span , но пример который указан там у меня не работает